# Node.js sharing code between backend and frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I want to share some code between node.js back-end and front-end, like converting a certain date format (not natively supported by Date) into Date object.

First off, if sharing code between backend and frontend is terrible practice, let me know.

If not: the problem I am running into is that for node.js, I would use a module, and use module.exports to export the util functions. I want to avoid using [front-end modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) for more browser support. So how could I use the same js file in backend and frontend?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to use `.js` files both in `node` and on the front-end is to check for `module` and `module.export` objects before assigning to them.

**Example convert-date.js file:**

```
function convertDate(date) {
   // blah blah
}

if(this && typeof module == "object" && module.exports && this === module.exports) {
   module.exports = convertDate;  // for example
}
```

which results in declaring `convertDate` as a global function name on the front-end while allowng it to be required in node using

```
const convertDate = require(pathOfConvertDate.js);
```

To limit the number of globals created put more complex code inside an IIFE which returns the value to be exported:

```
const convertDate = (()=>{..... return convertDate;})();
if( this etc...) module.exports = convertDate;
```

---

A variation of the above is to mandate the presence of a common utilities object on the front-end which must be declared before file inclusion. Using `Util` as an example name, the export code becomes more like

```
if(this && typeof module == "object" && module.exports && this === module.exports) {
   module.exports = convertDate;  // for example
}
else if(typeof Util == "object" && Util) {
   Util.convertDate = convertDate;
}
else {
    throw( Error("Front-end 'Util' export object not found'));
}
```

---

FWIW I don't know how common this kind of usage is. I do know it works with `file://` protocol and simplifies writing test code that runs equally well on the back or front-end.